# Why do my data frames create new rows when concatenated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to merge tow data frames. One has shape of `1725 rows x 3 columns` and the other has `1725 rows x 8 columns`.

I merge them with `res = pd.concat([dataSet, onehotDataFrame], axis=1)` and get a data frame of shape
`1810 rows x 11 columns`.

The columns seem ok but why are there 85 extra rows in the result?

It is important to note that the original data has shape `(1810, 7)` and I use

```py
extractedCols = remove_columns(originalDF, remove_from_all)
noDuplacates = extractedCols.drop_duplicates()
```

to get a `(1725, 4)` data frame I then remove another column before the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is different index values, so you need same by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = pd.concat([dataSet.reset_index(drop=True),
                onehotDataFrame.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Another idea is set one index by another before [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dataSet.index = onehotDataFrame.index
df = pd.concat([dataSet, onehotDataFrame], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In another simple way, you may write both data with `df.to_csv()` and then read your data again with `df.read_csv()`. In this way, your index will be fine as you like.